# Feature Selection in Text Classification

Tags: text, document-classification

I'm currently studying on text classification, focusing on feature selection. Can anyone suggest me any software/program that I can use for text classification that provides feature selection function (particularly Information Gain, Chi Square, Odds Ratio, Mutual Information, etc.)?

Thanks and best regards =)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow :)  This question is perhaps too broad and too subjective to be easily answered.  It also doesn't fulfil one of the golden rules - which is to say what you've tried.  In this case, have you done a google search?  Have you tried any candidate APIs/Tools etc and found them wanting in some way?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the broad question =). Anyway, I've tried WEKA and RapidMiner and it provides function for text classification as well as feature selection using Information Gain and Chi-Square. I'd also like to implement Odds Ratio, Mutual Information and etc. to see the differences.